# Improve Mahout suggestions

Tags: mahout, autosuggest, mahout-recommender

I'm searching for the way to improve Mahout suggestions (form Item-based recommender, and data sets originally are user/item/weight) using an 'external' set of data.

Assuming we already have recommendations: a number of Users were suggested by the number of items.

But also, it's possible to receive a feedback from these suggested users in a binary form: 'no, not for me' and 'yes, i was suggested because i know about items'; this way 1/0 by each of suggested users.

What's the better and right way to use this kind of data? Is there any approaches built-in Mahout? If no, what approach will be suitable to train the data set and use that information in the next rounds?

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal that you get explicit user feedback as 0-1 (strongly disagree - strongly agree), otherwise the feedback could be treated as any other user rating from the input. 
Anyway you can introduce this user feedback in you initial training set, with `recommended score` ('1' feedback) or `1 - recommended score` ('0' feedback) as weight and retrain your model.

It would be nice to add a 3-rd option 'neutral' that does not do anything, to avoid noise in the data (e.g. recommended score is 0.5 and user disagrees, you would still add it as 0.5 regardless...) and model over fitting.

Comment: Yeah, boolean data sets are not ideal, but even if we'll assume that we have a 'normal' weight (let's say from 1 to 5) as user's feedback, that still doesn't answers the question about *how* we use the data in the upcoming suggestion results evaluations. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at 'Comparison of Implicit and Explicit Feedback from an Online Music Recommendation Service' by Jawaheer. What I was suggesting above is to transform your implicit feedback to an explicit one and retrain your model.

Comment: Also take a look at this presentation on 'Denoising user feedback' http://www.slideshare.net/xamat/the-science-and-the-magic-of-user-feedback-for-recommender-systems

Answer (score 1):

Boolean data IS ideal but you have two actions: "like" and "dislike"

The latest way to use this is by using indicators and cross-indicators. You want to recommend things that are liked so for this data you create an indicator. However it is quite likely that a user's pattern of "dislikes" can be used to recommend likes, for this you need to create a cross-indicator.

The latest Mahout SNAPSHOT-1.0 has the tools you need in *spark-itemsimilarity". It can take two actions, one primary the other secondary and will create an indicator matrix and a cross-indicator matrix. These you index and query using a search engine, where the query is a user's history of likes and dislikes. The search will return an ordered list of recommendations.

By using cross-indicators you can begin to use many different actions a user takes in your app. The process of creating cross-indicators will find important correlations between the two actions. In other words it will find the "dislikes" that lead to specific "likes". You can do the same with page-views, applying tags, viewing categories, almost any recorded user action.

The method requires Mahout, Spark, Hadoop, and a search engine like Solr. It is explained here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html under **How to use Multiple User Actions**